# YouTube Data API track if users watch the entire video

Tags: android, ios, video, youtube

Our application needs to be able to track how many minutes of a video was viewed. If the user stops or pauses the video we need to be able to start up the video at the last point viewed. We also need to know if the user watched the entire video.

Can anyone tell me if the YouTube data API allows this?

Comment: Surely the YouTube API documentation would tell you?